# Blank fragment is displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

### I am creating a food ordering app . I am fetching the list of restaurants using volley .

**Error:**
The restaurant list does not displayed and in the logcat window the following displayed:
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 
**What I have tried to resolve:**

1. used postman to verify volley response,the response is as expected
2. made sure if the variables were received in the right order
3. made sure that the array was received in the right format.

I attach the code of the HomeFragment and the adapter file

**HomeFragment.class**

```
    class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    
        lateinit var recyclerRestaurant: RecyclerView
        lateinit var progressLayout: RelativeLayout
        lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
        lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RestaurantRecyclerAdapter
    
        var restaurantList = arrayListOf<Restaurant>()
    
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    
                val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
                setHasOptionsMenu(true)
                recyclerRestaurant = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerRestaurant)
                progressLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.progressLayout)
                progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                progressLayout.visibility= View.VISIBLE
    
    
    
                val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity as Context)
                val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v2/restaurants/fetch_result/"
                if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(activity as Context)) {
    
                    val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.GET,url , null,
                        Response.Listener<JSONObject>{
                            progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                            try {
                                val data = it.getJSONObject("data")
                                    val success = data.getBoolean("success")
                                if (success) {
                                    val data = it.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("data")
                                    for(i in 0 until data.length()) {
                                        val resObject = data.getJSONObject(i)
                                        val restaurants = Restaurant(
                                            resObject.getString("id").toInt(),
                                            resObject.getString("name"),
                                            resObject.getString("rating"),
                                            resObject.getString("cost_per_person"),
                                            resObject.getString("image_url")
    
                                        )
                                        restaurantList.add(restaurants)
    
                                        if(activity != null) {
                                            recyclerAdapter = RestaurantRecyclerAdapter(activity as Context, restaurantList)
                                            val mLayoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                                            recyclerRestaurant.layoutManager =mLayoutManager
                                                recyclerRestaurant.adapter = recyclerAdapter
                                            recyclerRestaurant.setHasFixedSize(true)
    
                                        }
    
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        activity as Context,
                                        "some error has occurred",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }catch (e: JSONException){
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        },
                        Response.ErrorListener {
                            if(activity != null){
                                Toast.makeText(activity as Context,"Volley error has occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
                        }) {
    
                        override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                            headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                            headers["token"] = "06f579db533924"
                            return headers
                        }
    
                    }
    
                    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
                }else{
                    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
                    dialog.setTitle("error")
                    dialog.setMessage("Internet connection not found")
                    dialog.setPositiveButton("open settings"){ text, listener->
                        val settingsIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)
                        startActivity(settingsIntent)
                        activity?.finish()
                    }
                    dialog.setNegativeButton("exit"){text,listener->
                        ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(activity as Activity)
                    }
                    dialog.create()
                    dialog.show()
                }
                return view
    
            }
    
    
    }
```

**RestaurantRecyclerAdapter.class**

```
    class RestaurantRecyclerAdapter(val context:Context, val itemList: ArrayList<Restaurant> ):RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantRecyclerAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder>() {
        class RestaurantViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
            val txtRestaurantName :TextView=  view.findViewById(R.id.txtRestaurantName)
            val imgRestaurantImage :ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgRestaurantImage)
            val txtRating : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRating)
            val txtPerPerson : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtPerPerson)
            val llContent : LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.llContent)
    
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RestaurantViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_single_row,parent,false)
            return RestaurantViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return itemList.size
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RestaurantViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val restaurant = itemList[position]
            holder.txtRestaurantName.text = restaurant.name
            holder.txtRating.text = restaurant.rating
            holder.txtPerPerson.text = restaurant.cost_per_person
            Picasso.get().load(restaurant.image).error(R.drawable.ic_food).into(holder.imgRestaurantImage)
```

Comment: Move your logic to the OnViewCreated function. Only use the onCreateView to inflate the view.

Comment: I implemented that but I'm getting the same error

Comment: change var restaurantList = arrayListOf<Restaurant>() to var restaurantList = ArrayList<Restaurant>()

Comment: I implemented that but I'm still getting the same error